# Palindrome: finding the shortest possible string

Tags: javascript, palindrome

The task is the following: "Write a JavaScript program to find the shortest possible string which can create a string to make it a palindrome by adding characters to the end of it."

This is the code I am looking at:

```
function build_Palindrome(new_str) {
  var flag;
  for (var i = new_str.length;; i++) {
    flag = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < i - j - 1; j++) {
      if (i - j - 1 < new_str.length && new_str[j] != new_str[i - j - 1]) {
        flag = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag) {
      for (var j = new_str.length; j < i; j++) {
        new_str += new_str[i - j - 1];
      }
      return new_str;
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
console.log(build_Palindrome("abcddc"))
```

Output:

```
abcddcba
```

My question: At first it starts with `j=0`. If in the `for` loop, `flag=false`, then how does it proceed? Is `i=7` (`i++`?) and is `j=0` or `j=1`?

Comment: What have you done to investigate this yourself?

Comment: I tried to figure out how the code works. I found some articles and algorithm on Palindrome but they are for determining if the word or string of words is palindrome or not which is different. The above mentioned task looks more complicated.

Comment: Why don't you simply add a few `console.log` statements in the code and examines what it shows when you run it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Thank you buddy. It looks like it shows what I need. I can now investigate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **console.log** or any debugger to debug.

For your situation, you if the **flag** is false, it will break the loop of **j** and go to its outer loop (**i** here)

I made the demo here:
https://repl.it/repls/LoyalProfuseRouter

You can see the demo (it come with my solution), and instead of break you can use simple loop to return your string, it more readable.

Comment: this function **f** is a demo for using **break** inside nested **for** loop

Comment: Ok. Thank youi.

Comment: no problem man. Keep up with stackoverflow although your question get some downvote from someone but keep in mind what you learned and how to make the question better next time.

Comment: Thank you buddy. I am new in the world of coding but study hard now.